# Grid table with hard line break in first line with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

How can I make pandoc create a cell with the first thing being a line break in a grid table?

The following makes latex say ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

```
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| X                                 | Y                                  |
+===================================+====================================+
|Total revenue:\                    | \                                  |
|  - Current year\                  | YYY\                               |
|  - Previous year\                 | XXX\                               |
|Total profit/loss:\                | \                                  |
|  - Current year\                  | TTT\                               |
|  - Previous year                  | ZZZ                                |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using linebreaks for layouting is frowned upon in Markdown and HTML. Because it's not [semantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML), but also because it often doesn't work well (like in your example).

I would make the table.... well, more tabular:

```
                                    X           Y
--------------  --------------      ----        ----
Total revenue:
                Current year        XXX         YYY
                Previous year       XXX         YYY
Total profit:
                Current year        XXX         YYY
                Previous year       XXX         YYY
```

Comment: Doing \mbox{} \ fixes the ! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end. I can not add more columns as the example is part of a larger table. Also the doc says " Note: in multiline and grid table cells, this is the only way to create a hard line break, since trailing spaces in the cells are ignored."

Comment: Was that a question? If so, I didn't get it. Anyway, since pandoc neither [supports cells that span multiple rows or columns](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-vs-Multimarkdown#tables) nor (ab-)using linebreaks for paragraphs, you'll have to adjust your table layout accordingly. I showed you one example. [This table generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\mbox{} \` will create the expected line breaks and no latex errors

```
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| X                                 | Y                                  |
+===================================+====================================+
|Total revenue:\                    | \mbox{} \                          |
|  - Current year\                  | YYY\                               |
|  - Previous year\                 | XXX\                               |
|Total profit/loss:\                | \mbox{} \                          |
|  - Current year\                  | TTT\                               |
|  - Previous year                  | ZZZ                                |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I have created an issue at github https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1733